# Sharing Maven profiles or settings.xml

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I'd like to define a few Maven profiles, where some proerties about JDBC connections are defined, make them available via HTTP and share them in my dev team, among several Maven projects. Ideally, I would like to just add a reference in a project's POM and have Maven download the profile defintions.

Is there a way to do that? Alternatively, can it be done via settings.xml, sharing such type of file the same way?

Comment: This can be done via settings.xml but each of devs will have to add these profiles to their own settings.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The professional edition of the [Nexus repository manager](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) contains a feature for managing and distributing Maven settings to users:

- http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/settings-sect-intro.html

A simpler solution would be to distribute these files on a shared and secured web server. Have you automated the development installation process?